# "Empty" inherited COM interface is not marshalled properly

Tags: com, marshalling, idl

I've got an in-proc COM server (dll, built in MSVC10), which is used in a C# client. One of the interfaces is defined like this:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(some guid),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IDerived Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IDerived : IBase{
};
```

The co-class implements both `IDerived` and `IBase` (and some other interfaces):

```
[
    uuid(some guid),
    helpstring("SomeClass Class"),
    noncreatable,
    hidden
]
coclass SomeClass
{
    [default] interface IDerived;
    interface IBase;
    // etc.
};
```

The co-class is apartment-threaded. When an MTA client thread acquires `IDerived` and tries to call any of its methods (inherited from `IBase`), it crashes somewhere in proxy/stub. In STA it works well, so I believe `IDerived` is not marshalled correctly. On the other hand, if I QI `IBase` explicitly or if I add a method to `IDerived`, everything works well.

Why the empty `IDerived` is not marshalled correctly?